# How to select and copy info from webpage using Selenium and send to IntelliJ console

Tags: java, selenium, web, intellij-idea, copy

How do I select/copy info from web with Selenium and copy into IntelliJ to String? I'm using IntelliJ in Java. I am trying to use:

```
Navegador.getInstance().instanciaNavegador().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='cpf']/span[2]")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "v"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `Navegador` does and it really does not matter. The key here are the Selenium methods you are invoking. For example, to *write* to a web element, `sendKeys()` is appropriate. But, based on the description of your post, you need to *read* from the page and not write to it. One way to obtain the text from a page is

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")); // Provide the XPath expression for the element containing the text you need.
String myText = myElement.getText();  // Saves the obtained text into a String object
```

Outside of this, I am not sure what else you need. Again, based on the limited information here, this seems all you need.

Answer (score 0):

To select and copy any info from any webpage using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and send it to the IntelliJ console you can use the following solution:

```
//required imports
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

// simulating CONTROL + A
driver.findElement(By.foo("bar")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
// simulating CONTROL + C
driver.findElement(By.foo("bar")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "c"));
// extracting the text from the clipboard
String myText = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor); 
// printing the text
System.out.println(myText)
```